# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'volume' of null

Tags: javascript, html

At this moment I'm quite frustrated.
I want to control a video via javascript:

- set the volume to 20%
- play & pause by clicking the video

That for I have this html (which also includes a little php)

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="player.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
        if(isset($_GET["id"])) {
                $video = $_GET["id"];
        }else{
                $video = "test.mp4";
        }
?>

<video id="video" preload="auto" autoplay="true"  loop="loop">
     <?php echo "<source src=\"$video\" type=\"video/mp4\">"; ?>
     <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
          Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
</body>
```

player.js:

```
var vid = document.getElementById('video');

vid.volume = 0.2;

vid.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (vid.paused == false) {
            vid.pause();
            vid.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Play';
        } else {
            vid.play();
            vid.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Pause';
        }
});
```

But Chromes console's just showing: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'volume' of null`
Why is that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: At the time your script runs, the video element hasn't been seen yet so it's not part of the DOM. Move your `<script>` tag to the end of the document body.

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the script tag at the end of body tag, currently your DOM hasn't been set when the script loads, hence it can't access elements from DOM.

Comment: thanks very much, i didn't knew that